# How plproxy select node when use "RUN ON hashtext(key)"?

Tags: postgresql

I have setup up working cluster of 4 PostgreSQLs servers with plproxy ( following  [plproxy tutorial](http://plproxy.projects.pgfoundry.org/doc/tutorial.html) ). One of the insert data function like following

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_user(i_username text) RETURNS TEXT AS $$
   CLUSTER 'queries'; 
   RUN ON hashtext(i_username);
$$ LANGUAGE plproxy;
```

My problem is how `RUN ON hashtext(i_username)` select a one node, since `hashtext(i_username)` can have large range of values. How this values mapped into 4 machines ? Is it using modulo operation ?

Answer (score 0):

[It uses bitwise AND operation](http://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=plproxy.git;a=blob;f=src/execute.c;h=bfd4b0f7892a9b3fe62adfd1ac1557cd6744f1e7;hb=01936d68da23b2e89bfbc3c7af9e492d3e4a973e#l945).  This works because the tutorial you mentioned stipulates that the number of shards has to be a power of 2.